# How does docker build know if a Dockerfile RUN or COPY line can use the cache?

Tags: python, docker

If my Dockerfile for a Python project looks like this:

```dockerfile
FROM python:3.7

# Set env variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

# Set work dir
WORKDIR /code

# Install rust
# Needed by cryptography package
RUN curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | bash -s -- -y

# Install dependencies from apt repo
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        build-essential \
        python-dev && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy and install requirements
COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache -r requirements.txt

# Copy code
COPY my_code /code/

# Set CMD
CMD ["python", "run.py"]
```

1. How does `docker build` know if `COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt` can use the cache, or if it needs to re-run this command?

   - Does the image made by running this command have metadata that keeps track of the hash of each file that was copied, so that next run, it can check if the copy operation will copy any changed files?
2. Can `RUN` operations ever be cached? How would Docker know when to use the cache, and when to re-run the command to build a new image layer?
3. If you disable caching completely, does that mean that commands like `COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt` that would have resulted in an unchanged image layer if cache was enabled, will likely result in a new image layer, with a different digest, completely negating the effectiveness of image layers?
4. Is there documentation somewhere that describes these rules for what can, and can't be cached?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache

Comment: @Ash-Ishh.. that answers almost all of my questions (except #3). Thanks!

Comment: Added the answer.

Answer (score 4):

1 - How does docker build know if COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt can use the cache, or if it needs to re-run this command?

> For the ADD and COPY instructions, the contents of the file(s) in the
> image are examined and a checksum is calculated for each file. The
> last-modified and last-accessed times of the file(s) are not
> considered in these checksums. During the cache lookup, the checksum
> is compared against the checksum in the existing images. If anything
> has changed in the file(s), such as the contents and metadata, then
> the cache is invalidated.

2 - Can RUN operations ever be cached? How would docker know when to use the cache, and when to re-run the command to build a new image layer?

> Aside from the ADD and COPY commands, cache checking does not look at
> the files in the container to determine a cache match. For example,
> when processing a RUN apt-get -y update command the files updated in
> the container are not examined to determine if a cache hit exists. In
> that case just the command string itself is used to find a match.

3 - If you disable caching completely, does that mean that commands like COPY requirements.txt /code/requirements.txt that would have resulted in an unchanged image layer if cache was enabled, will likely result in a new image layer, with a different digest, completely negating the effectiveness of image layers?

> Yes it will result in layer with different digest.
>
> To test it you can
>
> 1. `docker build -t test:latest .` build and note the hash of COPY layer
> 2. `docker save test > test.tar`
> 3. `tar xvf test.tar`
> 4. `docker build --no-cache -t test:latest .` build with no-cache flag and note the new hash of COPY layer
> 5. `docker save test > test.tar`
> 6. `tar xvf test.tar`
> 7. Compare {hash}.json of old COPY layer with {hash}.json of new COPY layer.
>
> The only difference between json is going to be the value of `created`
> key which is the date when layer was built.
>
> As per [this source](https://gist.github.com/aaronlehmann/b42a2eaf633fc949f93b#id-definitions-and-calculations) the `SHA256hex(uncompressed layer tar data)`
> is used to provide the layer digest and if you `cat {hash}.json | sha256sum` output is going to be same as name of file.
>
> Also for `negating the effectiveness of image layers?` I don't think
> it is negating the effectiveness at all, we are explicitly providing
> the instruction to not use cache.
>
> Even if `created` meta was not stored in layer, due to `no-cache`
> docker would have rebuilt the layer, it is just that the digest would
> have been same but the time to re-build the layer would have been
> there same as now.

4 - Is there documentation somewhere that describes these rules for what can, and can't be cached?

> First 3 answers are copied from https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#leverage-build-cache